# How do I store crawled data into a database

Tags: python, database

I'm trying to make a web crawler. I have this code that crawls a page in real-time and stores some URLs in a list, using the web2py framework:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
def crawler(url,x):
    crawled=[]
    tocrawl=[]
    def crawl(url,x):
        x=x+1
        try:
            page = urlopen(url).read()
            findlink = page.find('<a href=')
            if findlink == -1:
                return None, 0
            while findlink!=-1:
                start = page.find(('"'), findlink)
                end = page.find(('"'), start+1)
                link = page[start+1:end]
                if link:
                    if link!=url:
                        if link[0]=='/':
                            link=url+link
                            link=replace(link)
                        if (link not in tocrawl) and (link!="") and (link not in crawled):
                            tocrawl.append(link)
                findlink = page.find('<a href=', end)
            crawled.append(url)
            while tocrawl:
                crawl(tocrawl[x],x)
        except:
            #keep crawling
            crawl(tocrawl[x],x)
    crawl(url,x)


def replace(link):
    tsp=link.find('//')
    if tsp==-1:
        return link
    link=link[0:tsp]+'/'+link[tsp+2:]
    return link
```

How can I store this list into a database and update it at regular intervals, so that I can access the database and output the list of links on the web page periodically?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing the URL's into a list, why not write them to the db directly?  using for example mysql:

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect('server','user','pass','db')
curs = conn.cursor()
sql = 'INSERT into your_table VALUES(%s,%s)' %(id,str(link))
rc = curs.execute(sql)
conn.close()
```

This way you don't have to manage the list like pipe.  But if that is necessary this can also be adapted for that method.

Comment: does this update the database if it's put in a recursive code like mine or it overwrites the data in the database each time it is called?

Comment: it would add a new row each time.  as far as web2py goes, I have not used it before, but sqlite uses most standard sql syntax just fine.  just import sqlite3 instead of mysqldb and the connection string should just be a file name.  eg: `conn = sqlite3.connect('file')`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good job for [Redis](http://redis.io/) which has a built in list structure. To append new url to your list, it's as simple as:

```
from redis import Redis
red = Red()

# Later in your code...
red.lpush('crawler:tocrawl', link)
```

It also has a set type that let you efficiently check which websites you've crawled and let you sync multiple crawlers.

```
# Check if we're the first one to mark this link
if red.sadd('crawler:crawled', link):
    red.lpush('crawler:tocrawl', link)
```

To get the next link to crawl:

```
url = red.lpop('crawler:tocrawl')
```

To see which urls are queued to be crawled:

```
print red.lrange('crawler:tocrawl', 0, -1)
```

Its just one option but it is very fast and flexible. You can find more documentation on the [redis python driver](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py) page.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need a Cron. A cron is a job scheduler for Unix-like computers. You can schedule a cron job to go every minute, every hour, every day, etc.

Check out this tutorial http://newcoder.io/scrape/intro/ and it will help you achieve what you want here.

Thanks. Info if it works.